# Incrementation in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I m starting to learn the Ocaml code, in this exercice is required to count how many operation each function pasA and pasB will do, then I trying to plant a counter inside every of each function, so I m finding some issues in making it properly, and the code still give some issues, and that's why I would grad some help, Thank you in advance.

```
let i= ref 0
let incr()=
  i:=!i+1;;
let rec pasA n  = 
  if n=0 then 0 else pasA (n-1) ;
  incr();;
and pasB n = 
    if n=0 then 0 
    else if (n mod 2)=0 then pasA (n-2) 
    else pasA (n-1) ;
  incr() ;;
```

Comment: What is the issue? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: When I do compile I receive this message :                                                           This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
         int

1:Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.

Comment: Think about the type of `incr`. It's `unit -> unit`. It takes an argument of type unit and returns a value of type unit. That means `pasA` returns unit. But in `pasB` if `n` is `0` then `pasB` returns an `int`, otherwise it returns unit. These types need to agree.

Answer (score 2):

Say you change this function:

```
let myfun x =
    x + 1
```

Into this function:

```
let myfun x =
    x + 1;
    incr ()
```

The first version of the function returns an int value. The second returns `()`, which is known as "unit". In other words, you have completely changed the function.

This is just a long way of pointing out that you can't just add `incr ()` at the end of a function. You need to make sure the function continues to return the desired result.

You should also be aware that `;;` is not really part of the OCaml language (at least as most people see it). It's something you type to the REPL to get it to evaluate what you've typed so far.

If you remove all the `;;` tokens from your code you will probably avoid some other problems down the line.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer it was so helpfull .